# Insert line on facet_grid margin facets only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put a regression line on the marginal facets of a facet_grid, but I come up with a strange quirk where there are redundant lines on non-marginal facets also.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
data(diamonds)
```

Use plyr to build a data frame with the slopes and intercepts

```
regdf <- ddply(diamonds, .(cut), function(i)
               lm(price ~ carat, data = i)$coefficients[1:2])
```

resolve some naming issues

```
regdf$color <- "(all)"
names(regdf)[2] <- "intercept"

p1 <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(carat, price), data = diamonds, alpha = .4) +
             facet_grid(color ~ cut, margins = T) +
             geom_abline(aes(intercept = intercept, slope = carat), color = "red", data = regdf)
```

why do i get those superfluous lines on the D color row, and why are there numerous lines on some of those facets?

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm. This doesn't work at all in the development version.  Would you mind filing a bug at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues?

Comment: I found that changing  the `colour` or `group` parameters makes the multiple lines be removed. For example: ` geom_abline(aes(intercept = intercept, slope = carat, colour = carat),  data = regdf)